# What does "come to advance" really mean here? Does it simply mean "to achieve"?

Tags: word-meaning

President Obama indicated that Secretary Kerry would continue discussions with Foreign Minister Lavrov, the government of  Ukraine, and other international partners in the days to come to advance those objectives.

Answer (score 7):

You appear to be mis-parsing the constructions here.

- ***in days to come*** is a preposition phrase meaning “in the days which are to come”—that is, the immediate future.
- ***to advance those objectives*** is an infinitive phrase meaning “in order to advance those objectives”—that is, so that they may cause those objectives to move toward realization.